# How to properly stop a timer

Tags: c#, timer, locking

```
using System.Timers;

void CreateTimer()
{
    myTimerObject = new Timer(5000);
    myTimerObject.AutoReset = false;                 
    myTimerObject.Elapsed += MyEventOnElapsed;
    myTimerObject.Start();
}

void MyEventOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(aLockObject) 
    {
         myTimerObject.Stop();
         // Perform actions that can exceed the interval time set in the timer
         myTimerObject.Start();
    }
}

void MethodTrigerredToStopTimer()
{
    lock(aLockObject)
    {
        myTimerObject.Stop();
    }
}
```

In the above code, my elapsed event (`MyEventOnElapsed`) is going to take a while to complete and hence I had to use timer start and stop as part of that method. When `MethodTriggeredToStopTimer` is triggered, let's assume the code is at `MyEventOnElapsed` and reached lock, however the thread at `MethodTriggerredToStopTimer` wins the race and manages to get the lock, my timer will be stopped by the `MethodTriggeredToStopTimer()`. However once the lock is released, the execution pointer waiting at the lock(`aLockObject`) in `MyEventOnElapsed` will continue start/stop the timer indefinitely. How to handle timers in this situation?

Comment: System.Threading.Timer, System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a definitive way to stop via a method call or trigger when managing a loop like this, you will need to maintain some `boolean isStopped` or similar:

```
boolean isStopped = false;

void CreateTimer()
{
    myTimerObject = new Timer(5000);
    myTimerObject.AutoReset = false;                 
    myTimerObject.Elapsed += MyEventOnElapsed;
    myTimerObject.Start();
}

void MyEventOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(aLockObject) 
    {
         if (isStopped)
             return;

         myTimerObject.Stop();
         // Perform actions that can exceed the interval time set in the timer
         myTimerObject.Start();
    }
}

void MethodTrigerredToStopTimer()
{
    lock(aLockObject)
    {
        isStopped = true;
        myTimerObject.Stop();
    }
}
```

This would all be much neater in a nice little wrapper class, with the state variable named something like `Enabled` to avoid confusion with the naming similarities to the `Timer`'s `start` and `stop` methods. Additionally, I would take a look at building this loop using `Task`, `Task.Delay`, and `CancellationToken` as well if you end up needing cross-platform support or want to handle things like cancellation during your long-running operation.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to ask the timer whether the `Timer` is enabled before stopping (disabling) it. *That way, if `MethodTrigerredToStopTimer` is called it will realise it has been stopped on purpose, and not start it up again.*

```
void MyEventOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(aLockObject) 
    {
        if (myTimerObject.Enabled)
        {    try
             { 
                 myTimerObject.Stop();
                 // Perform actions that can exceed the interval time set in the timer
             }
             finally 
             {
                 myTimerObject.Start();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The `try finally` is helpful in ensuring that the timer is restarted by the time you exit the `lock` (even if an exception is thrown).